# Segfault with glPrimitiveRestartIndex

Tags: opengl, glew

I'm having trouble with `glPrimitiveRestartIndex`
My code compiles and links, but when I run it, it segfaults on the line:

```
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(0xffff);
```

`glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART)` gives me `invalid enumerant` when i poll with `glGetError` and `glGetErrorString`

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803295/primitive-restart-index-error-in-c-with-opengl), and it suggested that glew might not be initialized properly.

I'm initializing glew before I do this, and I'm also including the `glew.h` before `gl.h`.

Also, `glewinfo | grep Restart` gives me

```
glPrimitiveRestartIndex:                                     OK
glPrimitiveRestartIndexNV:                                   OK
glPrimitiveRestartNV:                                        OK
```

So shouldn't it work on my system? What could be wrong?

My code is fairly big, so I can't post everything, here is what I think is relevant:

```
if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()){
    // GLEW failed!
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize glew!\n";
    exit(1);
}
glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART); //invalid enumerator
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(0xffff); //segfault!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glPrimitiveRestartIndex
```

Is OpenGL 3.1 +
You should check to see if your driver supports it, by checking it like so:

```
if(GLEW_VERSION_3_1) {
  //we are running on 3.1 +
} else {
  //some version lower than 3.1
}
```